# How to prove the inequality $|x|^{r-1} \leq |x|^r + 1$

Tags: functions

$|x|^{r-1} \leq |x|^r + 1$ of a convex function?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by a convex function here?

Comment: I mean $|x|^{p}$ is a convex function.

Comment: Follow up question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/274986/how-to-proof-the-following-inequality

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, if $r\lt1$, then multiplying the inequality by $|x|^{1-r}$
$$
1\le|x|+|x|^{1-r}
$$
which is false near $0$. So let's assume that $r\ge1$, then
$$
|x|^{r-1}\le1\quad\text{if }|x|\le1
$$
and dividing both sides by $|x|^{r-1}$ yields
$$
|x|^{r-1}\le|x|^r\quad\text{if }|x|\ge1
$$
Therefore, if $r\ge1$,
$$
|x|^{r-1}\le|x|^r+1
$$

Comment: It is hard to choose one, but I like this one with truncation better.

Answer (score 6):

First of all, for $r>0$ we have that $|x|^r\leq 1$ iff $|x|\leq 1$. Moreover, if $|x|>1$ then
$$
  |x|^r = |x|\cdot|x|^{r-1}>|x|^{r-1}.
$$
As a result, whenever $r-1>0$ (which is $r>1$) we have that $|x|^{r-1}\leq \max(1,|x|^r)\leq1+|x|^r$

Comment: What is the above method you are using called? Is it very common? Where can I find more about it? Could you also show how to apply the Jensen's inequality here?

Comment: @RHS This is a common method that comes without name. Ilya splits the domain and estimate the expression $|x|^r$ in each domain. Also, this has nothing to do with Jensen's inequality - it is just a crude estimate.

Comment: BTW...... +1) :)

Comment: @AD. Where can I usually find this common method? And Did you mean the above inequality can't be proof with Jensen's inequality?

Comment: @RHS You will find this technique where estimates are needed e.g. in calculating various limits etc. Also, NO this cannot be proven using Jensen's inequality (joke) - I did not say that, but Jensen is a bit more subtle.

Comment: I believe that $r\ge1$ is necessary.

Comment: @robjohn: sure, I applied my inequality $r>0$ to $r-1$ in fact. Thanks for pointing this

Comment: I didn't accept your ans. because I have seen http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/26454/proof-that-if-higher-moment-exists-then-lower-moment-also-exists before asking, which isn't what I look for. Sorry. And still the one I accepted isn't what I am looking for. But I think to be fair I will ask in a new question.

Comment: @RHS: well, it's only yours choice what to accept, I don't mind this at all. But I'm just interested how seen this another question is relevant :)

Comment: For more detail you can see Feller's Vol 1 p. 277. In discrete case, the rth moment $E(X^r) = \sum x_j^r f(x_j)$. If it exist the (r - 1)th moment exist by the inequality above.

Comment: @RHS: ok, but I just wondered how this fact affects accepting answers :) anyway, that was just a question

Comment: Sorry. Which fact do you refer to? The previous reply I ans. how to relate the inequality to the question in stats.stackexchange as you had asked. Not a reason for choosing an ans.

Comment: I think using max function is more like a trick. That is. So I want to look for another ans. But I was looking for one using Jensen's inequality ultimately.